Pytest tests times out when running via `uv run pytest`
I have a few tests that use the pytest-timeout extension to act like benchmarks in the test suite, that look something like this:
@pytest.mark.timeout(10.0)
def test_something():
    # Do the test

I am observing failures with these tests, but only under the very specific circumstances of:

Running the test suite on Circle CI with a cimg/python:3.10.15 Docker executor
Running the test suite from a venv created by uv sync on the project, and then uv run pytest

The timeouts do not occur when pip-installing the project in the CI runner Python environment without using uv sync to create a venv and uv run. I've also observed the same slow-downs when manually measuring execution time of the test function, as well as when using an entirely separate poetry package manager and poetry run pytest.
So it seems that for some reason, executing these tests within a venv created by uv or poetry are leading to slower execution time, and I'm at a loss for why this is happening.
